# Tomcat7 deploying app with custom files

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, netbeans, deployment

This is the content of my netBeans project:

[image: NetBeans project content]

To use the folder called "ErrorSet" i use this line:

```
File file = new File("ErrorSet/error_list.xml");
```

It is necessary to import this file because it contains custom error codes, to the point:

When you want to import something in a netbeans project, the default "root" from where you use the files is the project name folder like [projectName]/ErrorSet/error_list.xml ...

Where do i need to place the ErrorSet folder when deploying the [projectName].war from dist folder in tocmat7 so that i can use new File properly? What does the File("ErrorSet/error_list.xml") parent directory become since its in tomcat7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that `Web Pages` and `Source packages` are different things.

To use the classes inside `Source packages` with custom files, you have to place your files inside a `Package` and use `getClass().gerResource()` like this:

In case the `ErrorSet` folder is a folder inside another package use this:

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("ErrorSet/error_list.xml").toURI());
```

And if the `error_list.xml` is in the same package as the class, simply use `getResource("error_list.xml")`.

Comment: This is fragile and not possible in certain environments. You should not use `java.io.File` at all, here.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `java.io.File`.

Instead, use a stream that you can get from the `ClassLoader`, like this:

```
InputStream in = null;

try {
  in = request.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/ErrorSet/error_list.xml");

  if(null != in) {
    // read the XML
  }
} finally {
  if(null != in) try { in.close(); }
                 catch (IOException ioe) { /* log this */ }
}
```

Now, put your file into `/WEB-INF/ErrorSet/error_list.xml` in your deployment.

This will work whether the file is on the file system or packaged up in an unexploded WAR file. It will also work in environments with a SecurityManager installed that won't allow the web application to read files, because the servlet container probably *does* have privileges to read those files.

Comment: Taking note of this, many thanks for your reply, will use this in future apps.